# Limit user resources on dedicated server

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, user-management, user-permissions

Is there a WHM plugin mode or something like that which would limit the amount of resources a user on a dedicated server can use (CPU and RAM) or ideally something which gives certain users priority access to the resources needed?

Because my problem is that some websites sometimes use all the CPU available (through MySQL) and then the other sites are very slow...

The closest thing I could think of would be [CloudLinux](http://cloudlinux.com). It allows you to limit how much CPU/memory a site may use before it gets capped, however it does not limit MySQL usage, pretty much just PHP. You could limit every site on the server to a specific amount of open process/CPU besides the one you want to have more resources.

Answer (score 1):

- [MySQL resource limiting](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-resources.html) -- per user, but not very fine-grained. Controls things like number of queries per hour. Userful as a hard upper limit, but doesn't apportion resources well or distinguish how intensive queries are to the server.
- [MySQL Governor](http://www.cloudlinux.com/docs/mysql_governor/) in CloudLinux monitors the user resource use on the server and adapts accordingly. It can be aware of CPU and slow query usage. If you don't want to change Linux distributions, you may be able to emulate that functionality. The individual package itself might also be under a free license. It was hard to say.
- [Apache has limits](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#rlimitcpu) for memory and CPU use. You can set those limits for each vhost.